# Adjusting the loss function for Support Vector Machines for SVC in sklearn

Tags: machine-learning, python, svm, libsvm

I have the following problem.

The minimization problem of the SVM that I want to solve is:

$$
\min_{w, b} \frac{1}{2}w^{T}w + \sum^{m}_{i=1}C_{i}xi_{i}
$$
Subject to:
$$
y_{i}(w^{T}x_{i} - b) \geq 1 - \xi_{i}
$$
$$
\xi_{i} \geq 0
$$
$$
C_{i} = \nu_{i}C
$$
where $\nu_{i}$ is some function.

Now the minimization problem that the base SVM solves is:
$$
\min_{w, b} \frac{1}{2}w^{T}w + C\sum^{m}_{i=1}xi_{i}
$$
Subject to:
$$
y_{i}(w^{T}x_{i} - b) \geq 1 - \xi_{i}
$$
$$
\xi_{i} \geq 0
$$

reference: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0957417414006228?via%3Dihub

or: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/268753346_Using_Volume_Weighted_Support_Vector_Machines_with_walk_forward_testing_and_feature_selection_for_the_purpose_of_creating_stock_trading_strategy

I was wondering is there a way I can change implement this in sklearn, its for a paper that im working.

Kind regards,

Cemal

Comment: I'm not sure if it's possible to make this change in `sklearn`, but this seems like a perfect job for CVXPY if you have a convex program (that depends on whether $\nu_i$ is an affine function). I've used it previously (actually, to implement the dual SVM algorithm) and it's quite well-documented -- it's plug-and-play with numpy mostly. For future reference, you might have more luck asking this on StackOverflow?

Comment: @tchainzzz I looked again at the documentation, i just changed for parameter C. If you think I can do this through CVXPY then yeah sure. Can you also solve the primal? Because in the paper, the dual of both base SVM and VW-SVM look the same. So I was wondering if you can do the primal... and dual if im not mistaken. Either way just a small change was added to the problem. Do you have examples? Could you show me?
PS: I did ask on stackOverflow, but they removed the question because it wasnt detailed enough. Peace!

Comment: Ooh, I wasn't aware that you could change $C$ dynamically for each example (which looks like what you're doing?). I think in the non-kernel setting, you can probably just plug everything in the primal (i.e. what you've written above); the dual form circumvents some dimensionality issues if your kernel-mapping is super high dimensional, which might not be a problem here.

Comment: I think the SVM example on the CVXPY website uses the dual problem: https://www.cvxpy.org/examples/machine_learning/svm.html (2nd code cell). I haven't worked through the dual of this particular problem, so I'm not sure how having elementwise $$C_i$$ terms affects everything. But you should be able to plug this in; this is the tutorial I used to learn CVXPY: https://www.cvxpy.org/tutorial/intro/index.html

Comment: According to the paper, it is supposed to significantly boost the performance of the classifier. How, exactly, my knowledge goes only as far as the paper. I checked out the references, which explains a bit more details: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0925231201006762. If you are interested. I will look at what you send a but later, and let you know if its works. Also, do you need to solve the dual, or can I stick to the primal?

Comment: This should just impact the individual bounds in terms of $0 \leq \alpha_i \leq C_i$ - this then will impact selection of the pairs to update, and the "clipping" logic when doing an update. It's really a very straight forward extension to SMO